# Parse specific columns with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following script set up:

```python
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("GetAif")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)    

schemaString = "c1 c2 id c3 c4 gender"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name 
           in schemaString.split()]
custschema = StructType(fields)

data_extract = sqlContext.read \
.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") \
.option("delimiter", ',') \
.option("inferSchema", "false") \
.load('/data/dataset.csv', 
        schema = custschema) \
.selectExpr("id", "gender)
```

the end goal is to extract the gender and id variables in one data parse.  I am fairly new to spark, so I am establishing that I want to minimize my operations.

I have attempted using:

```python
sc.textFile(/dataset.txt)
```

and a few operations thereafter, but that seemed to amplify the bad performance because of the number of operations.
Is there any better method which is potentially be cleaner?

Comment: `selectExpr("id", "gender)` does exactly what you're asking for...

Comment: However, `spark.read().csv("filename")` is the Spark2 way to get a CSV into a dataframe. SQLContext is not necessary

Comment: @cricket_007 that is correct - I was just wondering if this is most effective way to do this (the schema I had was a lot larger, and I was hoping for something to reduce the effort of listing every variable).  We're currently developing on < 2x though.

Comment: `SparkSession.builder` doesn't exist in Spark 1.x, but as far as I know, the only alternative would be to `"inferSchema", true`

Comment: @cricket_007 Apologies - I have corrected it.  Thanks for the help.